Expectation of brownian motion times exponential process
I want to compute
$$\mathbb{E}\left[B_t \cdot \exp\left(-\int_0^t\theta_s dB_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \theta_s^2ds\right)\right]$$
I couldn't find exactly the solution. Here is what I did, is it correct?
Let $L_t:=-\int_0^t \theta_s d B_s$. We introduce
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{E}(L)_t:=\exp\left(L_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle L, L\rangle_t\right)=\exp\left(-\int_0^t\theta_s dB_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\theta_s^2ds \right)
\end{equation*}
The question asks to compute $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[B_t\cdot \mathcal{E}(L)_t\cdot \exp(\int_0^t\theta_s^2ds)]$ under some probability $\mathbb{P}$. Assuming that $(\mathcal{E}(L)_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ is a true martingale on some finite horizon $T<+\infty$ (with further information about $\theta_s$, we would for instance use Novikov's lemma to assert it), the Girsanov's theorem states that under the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ defined as
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{Q}(A):=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbf{1}_A\mathcal{E}(L)_T]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbf{1}_A\mathcal{E}(L)_t]\quad \forall A\in \mathcal{F}_t
\end{equation*}
we have that $W_t:= B_t - \langle B, L\rangle_t$ is a brownian motion. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[B_t\cdot \mathcal{E}(L)_t\cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t\theta_s^2d s\right)\right]&= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[B_t]\cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t\theta_s^2ds\right)\\
 &= \left(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[W_t]+\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[\langle B, L\rangle_t]\right)\cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t\theta_s^2ds\right)\\
 &= -\int_0^{t}\theta_sd s\cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t\theta_s^2d s\right)\\
\end{align*}

By the Girsanov theorem, let $L_t := -\int_0^t \theta_s dB_s$ and $\mathcal{E}(L)_t := \exp\left(L_t - \frac{1}{2} \langle L, L \rangle_t\right) = \exp\left(-\int_0^t \theta_s dB_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right)$. The Doléans-Dade exponential $\mathcal{E}(L)_t$ allows us to define a new probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ by setting $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\big|_{\mathcal{F}_t} = \mathcal{E}(L)_t$. Under $\mathbb{Q}$, $W_t := B_t - \int_0^t \theta_s ds$ becomes a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion.
The expectation is written as
$$
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[B_t \cdot \mathcal{E}(L)_t \cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right)\right].
$$
Using the Girsanov theorem, this can be expressed under $\mathbb{Q}$ as
$$
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[B_t \cdot \mathcal{E}(L)_t \cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[B_t] \cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right).
$$
Under $\mathbb{Q}$, $B_t = W_t + \int_0^t \theta_s ds$, and $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[W_t] = 0$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[B_t] = \int_0^t \theta_s ds$. Substituting this back,
$$
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[B_t \cdot \exp\left(-\int_0^t \theta_s dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right)\right] = \int_0^t \theta_s ds \cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t \theta_s^2 ds\right).
$$
